# Spring boot Post request not saving foreign key

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have entities Job and worker. Worker can have multiple Jobs

```
@Entity
public class Worker {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int workerId;
    
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "worker", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Job> jobs;

    public int getWorkerId()
    {
        return workerId;
    }

    public void setWorkerId(int aInWorkerId)
    {
        workerId = aInWorkerId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Job> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void setJobs(List<Job> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Worker [id=" + workerId + ", name=" + name + ", jobs=" + jobs + "]";
    }   
}

@Entity
public class Job 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String description;
    
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status = Status.CLOSE;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="worker_id")
    private Worker worker;
    
    @Column(name="creation_time")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp creationTime;
    
    @Column(name="last_update_time")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp lastUpdateTime;
    
    @Column(name="expiration_time")
    private Timestamp expirationTime;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Worker getWorker() {
        return worker;
    }

    public void setWorker(Worker worker) {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }

    public void setCreationTime(Timestamp creationTime) {
        this.creationTime = creationTime;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastUpdateTime() {
        return lastUpdateTime;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateTime(Timestamp lastUpdateTime) {
        this.lastUpdateTime = lastUpdateTime;
    }

    public Timestamp getExpirationTime() {
        return expirationTime;
    }

    public void setExpirationTime(Timestamp expirationTime) {
        this.expirationTime = expirationTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Job [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", description="
                + description + ", status=" + status + ", worker=" + worker
                + ", creationTime=" + creationTime + ", lastUpdateTime="
                + lastUpdateTime + ", expirationTime=" + expirationTime + "]";
    }
}
```

I am using Spring data rest and Spring data jpa and my database sql scripts are

```
CREATE TABLE `job` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `creation_time` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `expiration_time` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update_time` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `worker_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKjdvw5xn9ojaarulg2lh2yrpih` (`worker_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKjdvw5xn9ojaarulg2lh2yrpih` FOREIGN KEY (`worker_id`) REFERENCES `worker` (`worker_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `worker` (
  `worker_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`worker_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_2r1ixytxcsbyy8korfyf3ylgd` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Using postman, I have first created Worker

```
{
    "name": "ankit"
}
```

And then I am creating Job

```
{
    "name": "job1",
    "description": null,
    "status": "CLOSE",
    "worker": {
        "workerId" : 1
    }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that the workerId value is ignored and is null. It is dropping it's value. What could be the reason for it. Have I failed to configure bidirectional oneToMany relation.
Below are the logs in which worker_id is null

```
insert into job (creation_time, description, expiration_time, last_update_time, name, status, worker_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-11-19 15:31:28.026 TRACE 10320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-11-19 15:31:28.002]
2020-11-19 15:31:28.028 TRACE 10320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-11-19 15:31:28.028 TRACE 10320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2020-11-19 15:31:28.028 TRACE 10320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2020-11-19 15:31:28.002]
2020-11-19 15:31:28.028 TRACE 10320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [job1]
2020-11-19 15:31:28.028 TRACE 10320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [CLOSE]
2020-11-19 15:31:28.029 TRACE 10320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [7] as [INTEGER] - [null]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the absolute URI to the worker and avoid wrapping the worker id. The body of the post request should look like this:

```
{
   "name":"job1",
   "description":null,
   "status":"CLOSE",
   "worker":"http://localhost:8080/workers/1"
}
```

Here the Spring boot console output (while reproducing I omitted fields whose class I didn't know):

```
Hibernate: insert into job (id, description, name, worker_id) values (null, ?, ?, ?)
2020-12-11 17:38:02.581 TRACE 6269 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2020-12-11 17:38:02.581 TRACE 6269 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [job1]
2020-12-11 17:38:02.581 TRACE 6269 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```